# Write to serial port in assembly codes in a multi-thread system

Tags: multithreading, assembly, serial-port

I am working on a project which runs some assembly codes in a multi-thread system. Each thread is running the same assembly codes and at the end of the code, I would like each thread to generate a "finish" signal to the serial port so that I can log in from another computer. I know how to write to a serial port in assembly (http://cs.smith.edu/~thiebaut/ArtOfAssembly/CH13/CH13-3.html). 
However, I am not sure how it will work in a multi-thread system, as some threads may attempt to write to the serial port simultaneously. Does anyone have experience in this matter?

Comment: You'll probably need to use a mutex to ensure that only one thread writes to the serial port at a time. Alternatively, have the other threads queue up serial port write requests, and have only one thread do the actual writing.

Comment: You are writing to a serial port in assembler?  Serial ports are so slow that you could write your driver in Ruby and it would still be fast enough, (just).  Why not C or C++?

Comment: Oh... int 14h?  Does that stuff still work?

Comment: ..and if it does, is it an interrupt driver 'cos, if not, it's not gonna play well with a multitasker.

Comment: Unfortunately we are limited to only assembly codes, otherwise it will be much easier in C or C++. I actually haven't tried the codes (int 14h) from the URL that I posted, does anyone have a better suggestion in how to generate an output to serial port in assembly codes?

Comment: the answer to the question is this being a bios call how does the bios in question handle a multi-core processor?  If at all.  And if so how?  There are two basic answers.  It doesnt support it and that means you have to use a standard solution to share, or it does support it and you dont care, just do your bios call directly and the threading nature of the processor will just work.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS will not allow several threads to open the same serial port. This way you have to provide a proper error check and some port sharing mechanism.

For example, if the port is busy in this moment, your thread can try to wait some random time before the next attempt to open the port.

Also, releasing the port, when not needed is essential in such applications.